# ASP.net can't set checkboxes value!

Tags: asp.net, checkbox

```
CheckBox newBox = new CheckBox();
newBox.Text = dtCommon[i].userName;
newBox.CssClass = "cbox";
newBox.Attributes["value"] = dtCommon[i].id.ToString();
ApprovalSelectPanel.Controls.Add(newBox);
```

Renders as:

```
<input id="ctl00_mainContent_ctl00" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$mainContent$ctl00" checked="checked" />
```

How can I get a value attribute on?  My JQuery needs to access this!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I bet you it is setting the attribute, but on the containing span (look up one element).

You want to use the [InputAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox.inputattributes.aspx) property instead:

```
newBox.InputAttributes["value"] = dtCommon[i].id.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 newBox.Attributes.Add("yourAttributeName", "yourAttributeValue");
```

**EDIT:** Sorry I forgot checkboxes act a little diff so you need to do:

```
newBox.InputAttributes.Add("yourAttributeName", "yourAttributeValue");
```

If you want to access the `span` around the checkbox control the original would work or you could do:

```
newBox.LabelAttributes.Add("yourAttributeName", "yourAttributeValue");
```

Comment: Still not rendering any value attribute

Answer (score 0):

Can you try `newBox.Attributes.Add("Value", dtCommon[i].id.ToString());`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to store a value on the checkbox, I recommend using something besides value, such as "MyValue".   You can still get this "MyValue" using the .Attributes method later in your processing.   In jquery, you could use the .attr('MyValue') to obtain the value.